# Constructor is Ambiguous error .NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm new to Web API. In my .NET Core 3.1 web api I have defined 3 constructors beleiving overloading.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class KipController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly dbLNePMODev1Context _context;
    public KipController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
    public KipController(IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public KipController(dbLNePMODev1Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    ......
```

But when executing the application it says the following error

> System.AggregateException   HResult=0x80131500   Message=Some services
>   are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service
>   descriptor 'ServiceType: epmoAPI.Models.dbLNePMODev1Context Lifetime:
>   Scoped ImplementationType: epmoAPI.Models.dbLNePMODev1Context': Unable
>   to activate type 'epmoAPI.Models.dbLNePMODev1Context'. The following
>   constructors are ambiguous: Void
>   .ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions) Void
>   .ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[epmoAPI.Models.dbLNePMODev1Context]))
>   Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection   StackTrace:    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1
>   serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection
>   services, ServiceProviderOptions options)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection
>   containerBuilder)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object
>   containerBuilder)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()    at
>   epmoAPI.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Projects\Enterprise
>   PMO\ePMOHub\epmoAPI\Program.cs:line 16
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
>       [External Code]
>
> > Inner Exception 1: InvalidOperationException: Error while validating
> >     the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> >     epmoAPI.Models.dbLNePMODev1Context Lifetime: Scoped
> >     ImplementationType: epmoAPI.Models.dbLNePMODev1Context': Unable to
> >     activate type 'epmoAPI.Models.dbLNePMODev1Context'. The following
> >     constructors are ambiguous: Void
> >     .ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions) Void
> >     .ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[epmoAPI.Models.dbLNePMODev1Context])
> >
> > Inner Exception 2: InvalidOperationException: Unable to activate type
> >     'epmoAPI.Models.dbLNePMODev1Context'. The following constructors are
> >     ambiguous: Void .ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions)
> >     Void
> >     .ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[epmoAPI.Models.dbLNePMODev1Context])

Please help me. I am not getting an idea whats wrong in my code

Comment: why do you have 3 constructors instead of one that take 3 arguments ?

Comment: Sorry I am very new to DI. So honestly no idea how to deal with it. Thats why I made it 3

Answer (score 1):

Your `IConfiguration` (and probably `IMapper`) use dependency injection, while `dbLNePMODev1Context` does not. That's why ASP.NET Core can't instantiate it.

A cleaner solution:

```
public KipController(IConfiguration configuration = null, IMapper mapper = null, dbLNePMODev1Context context = null)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
    _mapper = mapper;
    _context = context;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I just tried that and its triggering System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: epmoAPI.Models.dbLNePMODev1Context Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: epmoAPI.Models.dbLNePMODev1Context': Unable to activate type 'epmoAPI.Models.dbLNePMODev1Context'. The following constructors are ambiguous:
Void .ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions)
Void .ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[epmoAPI.Models.dbLNePMODev1Context]))'

Answer (score 0):

If your `dbLNePMODev1Context` class inherits from `DbContext` (If your project uses EntityFrameworkCore) then you can register `dbLNePMODev1Context` as a `DBContext` in `ConfigureServices` method. You can add `DbContextOptionsBuilder` to indicate type of DB, Connection String and other details.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
services.AddDbContext<dbLNePMODev1Context>();
...
}
```

If your `dbLNePMODev1Context` class does not use EntityFramework then you can just register it as a service .Please decide on Scoped,Transient or Singleton. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
services.AddSingleton(new dbLNePMODev1Context());
...
}
```

It would give a better idea if you share your `ConfigureServices` method from `Startup.cs` class.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using the default ASP .NET dependency injection container and you have more than one constructor in `dbLNePMODev1Context`. So the DI container doesn't know which constructor to use when registering the service.
Try to specify it explicitly:

```
services.AddScoped(serviceProvider =>
 {
    var options = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<dbLNePMODev1Context>>();
    return new dbLNePMODev1Context(options);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class KipController : ControllerBase
{
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
private readonly IMapper _mapper;
private readonly dbLNePMODev1Context _context;

public KipController(IConfiguration configuration, IMapper mapper, dbLNePMODev1Context context)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _context = context;
    }
     // Your other action methods go here...
}
```

This way, you can use any combination of the dependencies in your controller actions. Make sure to update your DI configuration accordingly in your startup class to inject these dependencies correctly.